# Create and array, then loop to find i then alert username

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Create an array and fill it with at least six usernames (i.e. “Sophia”, “Gabriel”, …) then loop
through them with a for loop. If a username contains the letter “i” then alert the username.

I have tried to make an array and create and "if" statement, then I want to make an alert. I know I am missing something, but I can't figure out what.

```
  let userNames = ['rachel', 'greg', 'mike', 'adam', 'susan', 'john'];

  if(userNames.includes('i')){

    window.alert(userNames);
  }
```

I would like there to be a window alert with the name "mike"

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop if you want to return the index value of the array.  In this case we treat the letter i as a regular expression by placing it between two forward slashes, and try to match that string in each array value. It then alerts you with the entire value (mike(

```js
    let userNames = ['rachel', 'greg', 'mike', 'adam', 'susan', 'john'];
      for(let i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) {
        if(userNames[i].match(/i/)) {
          window.alert(userNames[i]);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how includes works... for example:

```
const userNames = ['rachel', 'greg', 'mike', 'adam', 'susan', 'john'];

console.log(userNames.includes('mike')) // true
console.log(userNames.includes('i')) // false
```

To get what you want you can do something like this:

```js
 const userNames = ['rachel', 'greg', 'mike', 'adam', 'susan', 'john'];
    
    userNames.forEach(name => {
      if(name.includes('i')) {
        console.log(name)
      }
    })
```

Comment: Yours is more elegant than mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array with `forEach` then match it against a regular expression:

```js
const userNames = ['rachel', 'greg', 'mike', 'adam', 'susan', 'john'];
const regex = /i/;
userNames.forEach(name => {
  if (name.match(regex)) {
    alert(name);
  }
})
```

Or you could use `includes`:

```js
const userNames = ['rachel', 'greg', 'mike', 'adam', 'susan', 'john'];
userNames.forEach(name => {
  if (name.includes("i")) {
    alert(name);
  }
})
```